# ¿Como convertir números arabicos a números romanos con javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, lógica

Necesito un función para que un numero arabico del 1 al 10 pase a ser romano. Quiero realizarlo con `js` y `html`.

Tenia pensado hacerlo con `if` y `esle if` pero no se si es lo mas sencillo o rápido y efectivo, así que si alguien me ayuda, muchas gracias.

```
if(numero==1){
  //retornar I
}
else{
   if(numero==2){
   //retornar II
   }else{
   ...
   }

}
```

Comment: Lo mejor es hacerlo con un array, lo recorres de mayor a menor mientras descuentas el valor del `numero arabico` y muestas los valores romanos hasta que el `numero arabico` se vuelva 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El codigo que necesitas es realmente simple, lo que te recomiendo es esto:

```js
function romano(a)
{
 var x=Number(a.value);
 var letra;
 var mensaje;
 if (x>10||x<=0)
 {
  alert("Introduzca un numero entre 1 y 10")
 }
 else 
 {
  switch (x)
  {
   case 1:
    letra="I";
    break;
   case 2:
    letra="II";
    break;
   case 3:
    letra="III";
    break;
   case 4:
    letra="IV";
    break;
   case 5:
    letra="V";
    break;
   case 6:
    letra="VI";
    break;
   case 7:
    letra="VII";
    break;
   case 8:
    letra="VIII";
    break;
   case 9:
    letra="IX";
    break;
   case 10:
    letra="X";
    break;
  }
 }
 mensaje="<p> El numero "+x+" en romano es: "+letra+"</p>";
 document.getElementById("salida").innerHTML=mensaje;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/estilos.css">
 <title></title>
 <meta charset="utf-8"/>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/funciones.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <form>
  <p>
   Introduzca un número del 1 al 10:
   <input type="text" name="a" size="10"/>
  </p>
   <button type="button" onclick="romano(a)">Mostrar resultado</button>
  </p>
 </form>
 <div id="salida" class="salida">
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Espero que te valga.

Comment: ¿Podrías explicar a grandes rasgos qué es lo que hace el código que has pegado?

Answer (score 2):

Imagínate no solo necesitar los numeros del 1 al 10 sino del 1- 10000, ¿harias 10000 IFs?

Lo mejor es hacerlo con array, el siguiente codigo solo funciona hasta el 39, pero para mejorarlo solo debes de agregar valores a los arrays, y no asi hacer 10000 Ifs.

```js
function romano(a)
{
 var x=Number(a.value);
 var letra;
 var mensaje;
 if (x>39||x<=0)
 {
  alert("Introduzca un numero entre 1 y 39")
 }
 else 
 {
    var romano=["I","IV","V","IX","X"];
    var arabico=[1,4,5,9,10];
    var i=4;
    var letra="";
    while(x>0){
      if(arabico[i]<=x){
        letra=`${letra}${romano[i]}`
        x=x-arabico[i];
      }else{
        i--;
      }
    }
  
 }
 mensaje="<p> El numero "+a.value+" en romano es: "+letra+"</p>";
 document.getElementById("salida").innerHTML=mensaje;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/estilos.css">
 <title></title>
 <meta charset="utf-8"/>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/funciones.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <form>
  <p>
   Introduzca un número del 1 al 39:
   <input type="text" name="a" size="39"/>
  </p>
   <button type="button" onclick="romano(a)">Mostrar resultado</button>
  </p>
 </form>
 <div id="salida" class="salida">
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Te comparto la manera que yo aprendí a resolver este problema. En general, la facilidad aumenta generando los valores para todos los 9...

```js
 function romanos(number){

  const romanos = {
    M: 1000,
    CM: 900,
    D: 500,
    CD: 400,
    C: 100,
    XC: 90,
    L: 50,
    XL: 40,
    X: 10,
    IX: 9,
    V: 5,
    IV: 4,
    I: 1,
  }

  let resultado = ""
  for (let r in romanos) {
    //repeat es parte del iterador y lo que hace es que
    // repite r las veces que sean necesarias. ( dependiendo la division)
    resultado += r.repeat(Math.floor( number / romanos[r]))
    number = number % romanos[r]
  }
  return resultado
}


console.log(romanos(245))
```